# Syntax error Cygwin If Else condition

Tags: bash, if-statement, cygwin

I am using Cygwin to run a script, I am getting syntax error when i use if else condition.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with my script ?

> ./test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
>   ./test.sh: line 10:`else '

```
#!/bin/bash
date
schema=''
table='JJJJ'
first=${table:0:1}
echo $first
if [$first == 'J'] 
echo 'SUCCESS';
else 
echo 'error';
fi
```

thanks

Comment: You're missing a `then`. And a space between `[` and `$first`. May I suggest using http://www.shellcheck.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect:

```
if [ "$first" == 'J' ]; then
  echo 'SUCCESS';
else 
  echo 'error';
fi
```

Note the `then` statement and the double quote for the `$first` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use shellcheck.net for stuff like this. You have syntax errors around your `if`.

Correct code-

```
#!/bin/bash
date
schema=''
table='JJJJ'
first=${table:0:1}
echo $first
if [ $first == 'J' ] 
then
echo 'SUCCESS';
else 
echo 'error';
fi
```